# Create range in IE without selection or highlight

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, replace, highlight, paste

I need to `pasteHTML()` instead of text that is not highlighted. I know that if do something like `mySelectedText.createRange().pasteHTML()` then i will get what i want but how to make range for not selected text? The only thing i have in this case is only cursor / caret, that stands in the line i want to highlight and replace. Thanks for any help.

**Update:**

```
This is one line.
|This is ano|ther line.|
```

`|` - possible caret positions. I need to highlight whole line, where caret is. No text is selected.

Comment: More information needed, probably there is more unselected text in your page than in the selection. What and where exactly is that unselected text you want to include to your selection? Please provide a small HTML-snippet of these selections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure yet what you really need. The (IE-only) code below selects the line(s) where the caret/selection is, and returns the `textRange` object containing the line(s).

```
selectLine = function () {
    var range = document.selection.createRange(),
        origTop = range.offsetTop,
        origHeight = range.boundingHeight;      
    range.moveToElementText(range.parentElement()); 
    while (range.offsetTop !== origTop) {
        range.moveStart('character', 1);
    }
    while (range.boundingHeight !== origHeight) {
        range.moveEnd('character', -1);
    }
    range.select();
    return range;
}
```

This function allows caret/character/cross-line selection, and works also with non-editable elements, if there is a selection available.